# Select objects where all children have no grandchildren

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, squeel

I have the following three-level hierarchy of models:

```
class Parent < AR::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < AR::Base
  has_many :grandchildren
  belongs_to :parent

  attr_accessible :my_number
end

class Grandchild < AR::Base
  belongs_to :child
end
```

It is expected that all `Parent`s will have multiple `children`, but each `Child` may or may not have any `grandchildren`.

I want to retrieve all `Parent` objects for which all the `children` have no `grandchildren`. How can I do this? I'd prefer a Rails-way, and I have squeel available; but I'll settle for raw SQL.

Bonus points if you can give me all `Parent` objects for which all the `children` have no `grandchildren` *and* all the `children` have `my_number < 5`.

Comment: I note that, of course, `Parent.all.select{|p| p.children.all? {|c| c.grandchildren.empty? && c.my_number < 5}}` does the job. It's not exactly efficient, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of researching I think I got the solution by using `group` and `having` clauses.

You can add this scope to your `Parent` model. Notice we need to manually define the `joins` in order to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of the default `INNER JOIN` Rails generates. More info on [SQL JOINS here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join).

```
class Parent < AR::Base
  scope :with_children_having_no_grand_children, -> { 
    joins("LEFT JOIN `children` ON `children`.`parent_id` = `parents`.`id` 
           LEFT JOIN `grand_children` ON `grand_children`.`child_id` = `children`.`id`")
    .group('parents.id')
    .having('COUNT(grand_children.id) = 0 AND COUNT(children.id) > 0')
  }
end
```

And then you can use:

```
Parent.with_children_having_no_grand_children
```

For the second question, assuming `:my_number` is an attribute stored in DB, you can do:

```
Parent.with_children_having_no_grand_children.where(children: { my_number: 5 }))
```